# Create a dynamic html table and populate it with xml data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I need to create a dynamic data table which shows data by reading a xml

here is my xml

```
<DataTables xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://C:/FRM/xsd/DataTables.xsd" >
    <Table name="dt_EdgeCaseHome">
        <Header>
            <Column name="Username" type="String" />
            <Column name="Email" type="String" />
            <Column name="Password" type="String" />
        </Header>
        <Row>
            <Value>brian</Value>
            <Value>brianf@edge.com</Value>
            <Value>qwerty</Value>
        </Row>

    </Table>
    <Table name="dt_EdgeCaseRoute">
        <Header>
            <Column name="Username" type="String" />
            <Column name="Password" type="String" />
        </Header>
        <Row>
            <Value>Carl</Value>
            <Value>1qaz2wsx</Value>
        </Row>

    </Table>
    <Table name="dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum">
        <Header>
            <Column name="AppHeader" type="String" />
            <Column name="UserID" type="String" />
            <Column name="Service" type="String" />
            <Column name="Clients" type="String" />
        </Header>
        <Row>
            <Value>Contract</Value>
            <Value>47</Value>
            <Value>Agent</Value>
            <Value>Exodus</Value>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Value>Contract</Value>
            <Value>49</Value>
            <Value>Agent</Value>
            <Value>Prometheus</Value>
        </Row>

     </Table>

</DataTables>
```

I was able to read the xml and get the data to a json using the following code

```
var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./testscenario.xml', 'utf8');

var result1 = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
```

But, I'm not sure on how to proceed with rest.

What I need to do is create a table according to that data and populate the table with column names and row values.

What is the best approach to build this table?

Answer (score 0):

Let the client do it with jquery? No need for JSON then

```js
var xml = `<DataTables xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://C:/FRM/xsd/DataTables.xsd" >
    <Table name="dt_EdgeCaseHome">
        <Header>
            <Column name="Username" type="String" />
            <Column name="Email" type="String" />
            <Column name="Password" type="String" />
        </Header>
        <Row>
            <Value>brian</Value>
            <Value>brianf@edge.com</Value>
            <Value>qwerty</Value>
        </Row>

    </Table>
    <Table name="dt_EdgeCaseRoute">
        <Header>
            <Column name="Username" type="String" />
            <Column name="Password" type="String" />
        </Header>
        <Row>
            <Value>Carl</Value>
            <Value>1qaz2wsx</Value>
        </Row>

    </Table>
    <Table name="dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum">
        <Header>
            <Column name="AppHeader" type="String" />
            <Column name="UserID" type="String" />
            <Column name="Service" type="String" />
            <Column name="Clients" type="String" />
        </Header>
        <Row>
            <Value>Contract</Value>
            <Value>47</Value>
            <Value>Agent</Value>
            <Value>Exodus</Value>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Value>Contract</Value>
            <Value>49</Value>
            <Value>Agent</Value>
            <Value>Prometheus</Value>
        </Row>

     </Table>

</DataTables>`
var $xml = $(xml);
$xml.find("Table").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using this code it just shows the table names. What I need to do is get the column names and values within each <Table> </Table> tag and create a table for that data and display it in my web page. I'm using nodeJS with express framework and ejs as my view engine